# LD_DEBUG on FreeBSD

Tags: debugging, freebsd, ld, ldd

In Linux ldd has very useful option LD_DEBUG.

LD_DEBUG
(glibc since 2.1) Output verbose debugging information about the dynamic linker. If set to all prints all debugging information it has, if set to help prints a help message about which categories can be specified in this environment variable. Since glibc 2.3.4, LD_DEBUG is ignored for set-user-ID/set-group-ID binaries.

Can i do it on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will have to turn rtld debugging on in the source code in order for LD_DEBUG to have effect on FreeBSD. So, the short answer is -- no, LD_DEBUG does not do anything unless you rebuild runtime linker with -DDEBUG.

That said, there's still a lot of useful info that runtime linker can produce. See rtld man page for the details:
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rtld